# How to free some memory in Centos 7 with only VestaCP installed

Tags: linux, centos

I recently bought a server. I have Centos 7 64-bit on it, with VestaCP installed (with one wordpress blog added).. Only these things are installed, nothing else as per my understanding.
However, my memory usage is already 50% (512mb out of 1024). Is that much VestaCP with a fresh installation of wordpress consumes? because I was told VestaCP is very light.

Sorry for offtopic, but my question is.. Is there anyway I can check what processes are being using my memory and which ones are just using memory and I am not using them..
I mean, How can I free some of the memory usage on Centos..

I'd appreciate any sort of help,
regards

Comment: You should start by taking a look at `htop` and sort it by memory usage.

Comment: I installed `htop`, but after installing htop package, it is still not working.. :( It says command not found.

Comment: If you're sure it installed, then search for it.

Comment: How can I search for it?

Comment: `find / -name htop`

Comment: It returns nothing..

Comment: Hi there, here are the logs.. It says that package is downloaded, but when I install it I get this. http://pastebin.com/sSfiiHUM

Comment: Are you sure your system is 64 bits?  Check `uname -a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am newbie, so took me a time to figure out.
Bascially, in VestaCP, there are a lot of additional services running from default.
I wasn't using Mailbox (like clamd, exim, dovecot) and other mail related services.
I stopped all those services and rebooted my server.. The memory got down to 200mb out of 1024mb.. which is okay.. :)
I did it, by running the following command.

```
service clamd stop
```

So, always make sure that you are not running processes that you're not using..
I know for most it will sound simple, but hopefully for some newbies like me, it'll help.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure, you have performed following commands to install **Htop** on your CentOS 7(64bit) Server as "**root**" privilege user :

```
# wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
# rpm -ihv rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
# yum install htop
```

Optionally, you can also use preinstalled “**top**” command which is similar to “**htop**”